# XDocReport can't create report from InputStream java.util.zip.ZipExeption

Tags: java, xdocreport

I use code from xdocexample

```
 InputStream in  = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToTemplate);
 IXDocReport report = DocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
```

and have error:

```
2014-08-12 20:13:40,050 ERROR [STDERR] java.util.zip.ZipException: incomplete dynamic bit lengths tree
2014-08-12 20:13:40,085 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:147)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,096 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:154)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,097 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:90)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,097 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1135)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,097 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1109)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,098 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.io.XDocArchive.setEntry(XDocArchive.java:349)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,098 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.io.XDocArchive.readZip(XDocArchive.java:311)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,098 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.createReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:359)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,099 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.loadReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:326)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,099 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.loadReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:317)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,100 ERROR [STDERR]  at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry.loadReport(XDocReportRegistry.java:302)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,100 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.work.report.xdocreport.XDocReport.<init>(XDocReport.java:36)
2014-08-12 20:13:40,100 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.work.report.builders.XdocReportBuilder.build(XdocReportBuilder.java:49)
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help you because we don't know which document kind you are loading. XDocReport API can load any document which are XML zipped (docx, odt, etc) but you need well implementation.

Today, XDocReport can load docx, pptx, and odt.

So I suupose you are loading a bad document (perhaps a .doc which is binary files and not a zip which contains xml entries).